# It it possible to not use a desktop display manager and just use the DE's lock screen?

Tags: linux, kde, desktop-environments, sddm

I have a laptop running Debian Linux and KDE Plasma as the desktop environment. This is a pretty trivial issue, but I hate the look of SDDM and would prefer to always use KDE's lock screen by booting straight into it if possible.

Did look into configuring SDDM to do this, and asked on a Unix ricing subreddit some time ago, but didn't get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The breeze theme looks exactly like the KDE lock screen: go to System Settings -> Startup and Shutdown -> Login Screen -> Breeze.

You might also be able to run `startx` on login and go into KDE's lock screen `loginctl lock-session`.

Finally, you can enable autologin with sddm (under behavior in the same setting).